# How to have Flex grid of tiles, with full page width expander when tile 'clicked'

Tags: html, css, flexbox

On a normal width / size screen, I have a grid of 3 x 3 tiles that contain summary status information. I am using CSS Flex and all works very well on smaller screens, collapsing to a 2 column grid and finally a single column on mobile.

However, I am trying to figure out a way to have a click on any grid element open an expander beneath it with "extra detail". The expander should obviously be the full width of the screen.

So, for example, on a desktop, with a 3x3 grid, if I click on the first box, I want an expander to expand beneath the first row, filling the full width of the screen.

However, if I simply have a full width div display on click, it just pushes the 2nd and 3rd tiles down beneath. See image for better explanation!

[image]

Can anyone suggest a good approach here using flex?

Comment: Ok, so thanks to @Hoargarth, I have made some progress with this one. However, its not working properly for me. So have created a new Fiddle (based on this work) that illustrates what I am seeing on my end when I try to integrate.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/es80mx5o/

Comment: Please post enough code to reproduce the problem in the question itself.

Comment: @Michael_B, thanks for taking the time to look at my issue. The revised fiddle posted above is my trying to provide as much information as possible! Based on the response by Hoargarth, I tried to use his solution, but it wasnt working in a responsive case (or without using explicit dimensions), so I created the fiddle above to illustrate what I am seeing. Hopefully that makes sense? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. But what I'm saying is that all relevant code belongs in the question itself, not in a third-party site. What if that site one day goes bust? Your question then becomes useless to future visitors. Consider posting your code in a [stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here's an updated Version:
Most of the stuff should be commented, but I'm pretty bad at explaining. So feel free to ask if anything is not clear.

For the HTML part:
You need to seperate your "Clickable" Item and the expandable container into two seperate flex items. The order of them doesn't matter

For CSS  Part:
Simply give that expandable Container a width of 100% and hide them with `display: none`

Javascript (thats the tricky part):
1. For that item you clicked, you need the number of the current row's last item
2. isert the expandable flex item after that clicked
3. show the expandable

To have it reposition if you resize the window and get into another viewport, simply trigger the click again if the "items per row" is changing.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Hoargarth/mfg0vshL/

```js
//click event to expand the expandable
$('.flex-item').on('click', function(){
    //hide previous opened expandables
    $('.flex-item').removeClass('active');
    $('.flex-expandable').slideUp();
    //get target data
    var target = $(this).attr('data-target'); 
    //toggle the container
    var $triggered = $(this);
    var $triggeredElement = $('.flex-expandable[data-target='+ target +']');
    positionExpandableElement($triggered, $triggeredElement);
    $triggered.addClass('active');
    $triggeredElement.slideDown();
});

//we need to check on resize how many items are pe row, if it changes, trigger a click on a already opened item, so it positions itself at the right position
var containerWidth = $('.flex-container').outerWidth();
var itemWidth = $('.flex-item').outerWidth();
var itemsPerRow = Math.floor(containerWidth / itemWidth);

$(window).resize(function(){
    containerWidth = $('.flex-container').outerWidth();
    itemWidth = $('.flex-item').outerWidth();
    var newItemsPerRow = Math.floor(containerWidth / itemWidth);
 if(itemsPerRow != newItemsPerRow){
       itemsPerRow = newItemsPerRow;
        $('.flex-item.active').trigger('click');
    }
})

function positionExpandableElement(triggered, element) {
 /*first determine at which position your expandable element has to be, should be the first element of next row from triggered element.
  For this we need to know how many elements currently are in a row. Then you can position it after that element*/
  
  //get the item number where you have to insert after
  var allFlexItems = $('.flex-item');
  var itemsData = []; //we need an array of data-targets to get the number of element from the array index
  $.each(allFlexItems, function(key, el){
   itemsData.push($(el).attr('data-target'));
  });
  var elNumber = $.inArray($(triggered).attr('data-target'), itemsData)
  //elNumber now tells us the position of the element that got triggered
  //now we can calculate where we have to insert our expandable
  var rowNumber = Math.floor(elNumber / itemsPerRow);
  var insertAfter = (itemsPerRow * rowNumber) + itemsPerRow - 1; //we add itemsPerRow because we always need to skip the first row, -1 because array starts at 0
  //now that we now the last items number (even in responsive), we can insert our expandable on click after that element
  $(element).insertAfter($('.flex-item')[insertAfter]);
}
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.flex-expandable {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .flex-item {
    width: 45%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .flex-item {
    width: 30%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- for data-target you can use anything you want. Even something like data-target="this-is-my-first-container", as long as the expandable got the same like the item and it should be unique -->

<!-- The order of the Items dosn't matter, you could even randomize them -->

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item" data-target="1"></div>
  <div class="flex-item" data-target="2"></div>
  <div class="flex-item" data-target="3"></div>
  <div class="flex-item" data-target="4"></div>
  <div class="flex-item" data-target="5"></div>
  <div class="flex-item" data-target="6"></div>
  <div class="flex-item" data-target="7"></div>
  <div class="flex-item" data-target="8"></div>
  <div class="flex-item" data-target="9"></div>
  <div class="flex-expandable" data-target="1"></div>
  <div class="flex-expandable" data-target="2"></div>
  <div class="flex-expandable" data-target="3"></div>
  <div class="flex-expandable" data-target="4"></div>
  <div class="flex-expandable" data-target="5"></div>
  <div class="flex-expandable" data-target="6"></div>
  <div class="flex-expandable" data-target="7"></div>
  <div class="flex-expandable" data-target="8"></div>
  <div class="flex-expandable" data-target="9"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks very much for such a comprehensive reply. I am trying to adapt it to what I currentley have, but without success. The main issue seems to be that you are using fixed height / width and margins. My existing is responsive etc... and is using 100% of screen. Also, each individual tile has a variable height (based on its content), but each are made to be the same height by flex:1 in my case. I have updated your fiddle so that you can get a better idea of what I am seeing when I try your approach! Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry I absolutely forget to think about responsive in this case... It's a bit "hacky" to get this done, but you could try to get the heights of the elements and position it with $(element)'.css(). So you can dynamically get the height and set margins for it. I'll try to fiddle something later and let you know about it.

Comment: That would be brilliant, thanks for much! I will certainly owe you a few beers if you manage to figure it out!!

Comment: @Jablalr Sorry that it took that much time... I've updated my answer above, now it should be fully responsive. You should even be able to set the height flexible if you remove the hard height.

Comment: Hi @Hoargarth, that perfect! Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks soo much!

Comment: @Jablalr Glad I could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of @hoargath need just one fix for the last incomplete line:

```
insertAfter = insertAfter > (allFlexItems.length - 1) ? allFlexItems.length - 1 : insertAfter;
```